# Difference between FORECAST and FORECAST.LINEAR in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel 2016 has a FORECAST.LINEAR function and the old faithful FORECAST function.

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Office Support documentation/reference
[here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/forecast-function-50ca49c9-7b40-4892-94e4-7ad38bbeda99)

> In Excel 2016, this function has been replaced with FORECAST.LINEAR as part of the new Forecasting functions. It's still available for backward compatibility, but consider using the new function in Excel 2016

**So in Office 2016 they should be the same.** Note, they also take the same arguments:
[Office 2016 FORECAST.LINEAR docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/forecast-linear-function-38e2a419-7415-4037-8761-93f3992ace87)
[Office 2013 FORECAST docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/forecast-function-50ca49c9-7b40-4892-94e4-7ad38bbeda99)